# How to place bootstrap dropdown menu button in page-header on the right site?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The case seems idiotically simple, but I can not deal with setting the elements.

**What I have:**

[image: What I have]

or:

[image: bad]

**What I need:**

[image: button on the right]

Code:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7j02ke6/)

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="page-header">
    <h2>Header</h2>

    <div class="btn-group <!-- pull-right -->">
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="/Scope/New">Create</a>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable" role="menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Create as copy: </li>
                    <li><a href="/Scope/New/1">Test 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Scope/New/2">Test 45</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Scope/New/3">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clearfix` in `page-header` and also add `display: inline;` to `h2`.
This will fix your issue. (currently `h2` added inline, you can place it in your CSS file)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="page-header clearfix
  ">
    <h2 style="display: inline;">Header</h2>

    <div class="btn-group <!-- pull-right -->">
      <a class="btn btn-success" href="/Scope/New">Create</a>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable" role="menu">
          <li class="dropdown-header">Create as copy: </li>
          <li><a href="/Scope/New/1">Test 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Scope/New/2">Test 45</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Scope/New/3">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.page-header {
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    margin: 40px 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="/Scope/New">Create</a>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable" role="menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Create as copy: </li>
                    <li><a href="/Scope/New/1">Test 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Scope/New/2">Test 45</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Scope/New/3">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

thats all , u can use flex.

Answer (score 1):

add `clearfix` to `page-header`

```
<div class="page-header clearfix">
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="page-header clearfix
  ">
    <h2>Header</h2>

    <div class="btn-group <!-- pull-right -->">
      <a class="btn btn-success" href="/Scope/New">Create</a>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable" role="menu">
          <li class="dropdown-header">Create as copy: </li>
          <li><a href="/Scope/New/1">Test 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Scope/New/2">Test 45</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Scope/New/3">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```